# Using vagrant on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, vagrant

I need to setup a web server and a database server on EC2.
It should be easy to migrate to another service provider later.

Currently, I have a web server and a database server, each running on separate EC2 micro instances with software installed there remotely.

Can we run a vagrant box on these micro instances with pre-installed and pre-configured softwares like LAMP stack and use that instead. So I will end with 2 vagrant boxes , one for web server another for database server.

Amazon provides already means to copy an instance but it is copied to another EC2 instance only probably .. If there is need to move to some other provider, it will be same process of re-installing all. So, an own virtual box installed on Amazon's virtual box is what i was looking into..

I don't know how good or bad it is.. I doubt if this will affect performance as well. Please share your views. Target is to have env prepared locally and have flexibility to deploy it on any service provider easily.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Running vagrant inside your AWS box is probably not the right solution. Have you looked into the [Vagrant AWS provider](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws)?

That will allow you to setup and provision your AWS boxes with Vagrant and Puppet or Chef... if you are using Puppet or Chef to provision your servers then you will have a very portable "scripted" install for your servers that can easily be moved to another provider at a later date...

Comment: thanks Matt. that has been confusing me . .because if I had created a box and installed it inside an AWS instance , it would mean running 2  operating systems , one for Amazon instance instance and another for the vagrant box. I will check other options you cited.

Comment: If there are 2 web servers and 1 database server , I think I need to provision all 3 of them as 3 boxes inside  Vagrant ?

Comment: Yeah thats correct... this article is a reasonable example of setting up multiple servers with a single vagrant file... http://shawn.dahlen.me/blog/2013/04/12/manage-all-application-environments-with-vagrant/

It's using the digital ocean provider... but if you make it use the aws provider instead it should give you a fair idea! :)

Answer (score 1):

So running a virtual machine, on another virtual machine probably isn't the best. But if you want to install Vagrant on Amazon Linux you can do:

```
wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.2.4/vagrant_2.2.4_x86_64.rpm   
sudo rpm -ivh vagrant_2.2.4_x86_64.rpm
```

The RPM is the Centos version from the downloads page here: https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html

But then you cannot install virtualbox to run a VM. So it doesn't actually work anyways.

Comment: Possibly hijacking the question to provide technical advice.

Comment: what does this do exactly?! You just installed vagrant on EC2?

Comment: Yeah, it just installs Vagrant on an EC2 running Amazon Linux. However, Vagrant does not work as it relies on virtualbox, or some other virtual machine manager, and they don't appear to work on EC2s.